Why io.BytesIO is not a subclass of typing.BinaryIO, and io.StringIO is neither a subclass of typing.TextIO?
When use match-case pattern, I found that case typing.BinaryIO(): can not match object with type io.BytesIO.
So I try this:
import io
import typing

assert issubclass(list, typing.Sequence)
assert issubclass(list, typing.List)
assert issubclass(dict, typing.Mapping)
assert issubclass(dict, typing.Dict)
# assert issubclass(io.StringIO, typing.TextIO) # failed!
# assert issubclass(io.BytesIO, typing.BinaryIO) # failed!

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
c = io.BytesIO(b"123123123")
d = io.StringIO("123123123")

assert isinstance(a, typing.List)
assert isinstance(a, typing.Sequence)
assert isinstance(b, typing.Dict)
assert isinstance(b, typing.Mapping)
# assert isinstance(c, typing.BinaryIO) # failed!
# assert isinstance(d, typing.TextIO) # failed!

It shows that io.BytesIO and io.StringIO are not subclass of typing.BinaryIO and typing.TextIO, which in my opinion is strange since official documents never hint me to be carefule about this behaviour (or at least I never found it).
What is more strange is a .pyi stub file i found, its path is /data/users/XXXXXX/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2024.11.1/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/_io.pyi.
I found this line in the stub file: class BytesIO(BufferedIOBase, _BufferedIOBase, BinaryIO):, which implies that things should be as they should be for my intuition.
Is this intentional design or a bug? If is a design, why?
I'm using Python 3.12.3 with mypy 1.13.0, under VSCode 1.93.1 with pylance 2024.11.1 extension.

Classes in the typing module are not meant to be used for subclass / instance checks at runtime. Their only purpose is type hinting.

I'm rather surprised that issubclass(list, typing.Sequence) returns True

The .pyi stub file is most likely part of the pylance implementation and is not used by the interpreter which evaluates the assert statements

Classes in the typing module are not meant to be used for instance / subclass checks at runtime. Their purpose is type hinting.
If you want to use instance / subclass checks like that, check out collections.abc, especially this overview. For io.StringIO and io.BytesIO, their abstract base classes are io.TextIOBase and io.BufferedIOBase. Their common base class is io.IOBase.

I think more specifically, typing.IO and its children aren't meant to represent things like StringIO that, though file-like, aren't returned by open. The three haven't been deprecated like typing.List et al were.

Makes sense. Following the documentation you gave, I found that typing.Sequence has been deprecated (since 3.9), so I guess this inconsistency with the relationship between the concrete implementation classes is caused by the early implementation of the type annotation system.

There is one more small practical question remained. When annotating the types of function parameters, should I use io.xxx or typing.xxx?

@IsuxizSlidder for annotations I would use typing.xxx

@chepner note that typing.IO is the only generic I/O class. So, if somebody implements a buffered file like type that operates on other sequences than str or bytes, typing.IO[other_sequence_type] is the only way to annotate that.

typing.IO represents "real", effectual I/O, whereas the io.*IO classes are more like pure data structures the happen to have file-like interfaces. I didn't say typing.IO was useless; I explicitly pointed out that it wasn't deprecated like some other typing type hints, implying that it was still necessary in some cases.

@chepner yes, I fully agree with you. My comment was meant as a "it would be weird if typing.IO was deprecated". Sorry for not making that clear.

Oh, my bad :) We're on the same page, then.
